# Creating Column Names in Python Dataframe loop

Tags: python, pandas

Seems quite simple, after I added a loop, I tried adding column names, but my code keeps failing. Can someone help me where I can add the columns?

```
    x = range(1,25)
    y = pd.date_range(start="2016-02-01", end="2016-02-29")
    d2 = pd.DataFrame([a, b] for a in x for b in y)
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([[a, b] for a in x for b in y], columns=['x', 'y'])`?

Comment: If you find any answer helpful, accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following methods will help you:

```
# Add columns to dataframe
d2.columns =['a', 'b']

# Create dataframe with columns a and b
d2=pd.DataFrame([[a, b] for a in x for b in y], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
      a          b
0     1 2016-02-01
1     1 2016-02-02
2     1 2016-02-03
3     1 2016-02-04
4     1 2016-02-05
..   ..        ...
691  24 2016-02-25
692  24 2016-02-26
693  24 2016-02-27
694  24 2016-02-28
695  24 2016-02-29
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the extra square bracket in my code.

Comment: @user147271 No need to thank me, we help each other at the end.